# SSRS Conditional formatting switch expression only formatting numeric values

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

Trying to add conditional formatting on a field based on value, some values are numeric, others are letters.

I have tried both switch and IIF statements, but the below expressions only result in formatting the numeric values in my report.  I have checked the data to ensure there are no extra spaces or anything around the letter values, and changed the 'false' formatting to another color to see if that would color the letters, no luck.  What am I missing?

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Networks.Value = 2,  "LightBlue",
Fields!Networks.Value = "O", "LightBlue",
Fields!Networks.Value = 3, "Yellow",
Fields!Networks.Value = "H", "Yellow", 
Fields!Networks.Value = 1, "LightGreen",
Fields!Networks.Value = "V", "LightGreen",
Fields!Networks.Value = 4, "Plum",
Fields!Networks.Value = "R", "Plum")
```

```
=IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = 2,  "LightBlue",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = "O", "LightBlue",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = 3, "Yellow",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = "H", "Yellow", 
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = 1, "LightGreen",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = "V", "LightGreen",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = 4, "Plum",
IIF(Fields!Networks.Value = "R", "Plum", "Transparent"))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the numeric values in quotes. They all come from a single field as if that contains non-numeric characters then it must be a string so you must compare to strings.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Networks.Value = "2",  "LightBlue",
Fields!Networks.Value = "O", "LightBlue",
Fields!Networks.Value = "3", "Yellow",
Fields!Networks.Value = "H", "Yellow", 
Fields!Networks.Value = "1", "LightGreen",
Fields!Networks.Value = "V", "LightGreen",
Fields!Networks.Value = "4", "Plum",
Fields!Networks.Value = "R", "Plum",
True, "Red"
)
```

At the end I added `True`, this acts like an `ELSE` and catches anything that does not match the previous tests.

You could also trim the field before comparing, but you said you have already checked for this, but if you want to do that too just swap `Fields!Networks.Value` for `TRIM(Fields!Networks.Value)`

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately none of those worked - each were tried separately and in conjunction with one another.  Interestingly enough, adding the quotes to the numeric values actually caused those to no longer format/color.  I also tried then removing the quote from the letters, and as expected got an error that time.  Darn it, I was hopeful as those were great ideas.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data as text, I can't see any reason why it would not work. If you can script out a table and data that you can reproduce the error with then that would be useful.

Comment: Trying, but the text won't stay formatted properly so it's easily readable (list form) and I can't figure out how to do that here or post a screenshot.  This is how it keeps posting it:  Tractor Division Drv Type3 Networks
2324 HOPM COME 3    
2070 HOPM COME H    
1801 HOPM COME 3    
2053 HOPM COME H    
2121 VAN COME 1    
2014 VAN COME V    
2019 VAN COME 1    
2042 VAN COME V    
2085 VAN COME 1    
2356 VAN COME 1    
2060 VAN COMMW R    
2004 VAN COMMW 4    
2209 VAN COMMW R    
2083 VAN COMMW 4    
2008 VAN COMMW 4    
1930 VAN COMMW R

Comment: Click Edit to start editing your question, then paste the text in. Select the pasted text and hit the "Code Sample" button `{}` on the toolbar. You can also format it using table markdown (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) but it's better to script out the table creation and data insert so others can just copy/paste it easily.